# Autoroute step by step using Yours http request has a time lag

Tags: javascript

I want to set up a html page with gmap and autoroute step by step or point by point. I want to do that using YOURS (OSM) http request options.

It works fine, but at the end of the http request I must set a alert box "alert("OK?);" in order to get the correct route. If I comment that out, the rout will only be set, if I set the next point.

I tried and tried and ... perhaps someone can look over the (extracted) code from a hobby scripter (normally more vba/vbs as js).

best regards Reinhard

Ps: The code example works if you copy out and test local. Don't use "run code snippet" here, the alert box hangs.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Google Maps API and Autoroutes</title>
<!--Source code -->
<!-- Style to put some height on the map -->
<style type="text/css">
    #map-canvas { height: 500px };
</style>

<!-- Load the Google Maps aPI -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<!-- All of the script for multiple requests -->
<script type="text/javascript">


var map = null;
var info;
var marker;


function init() {

 // Some basic map setup (from the API docs)
 var mapOptions = {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.5, 6.9),
  zoom: 13,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  streetViewControl: false,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
 };

 map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
 info = document.getElementById('info');
 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}


//////////////////////routeCalc //////////////
var routeMarkers = [];
var setRM = 0;

function setRouteMarker() {
 if (setRM == 0) {
  temp = google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
     addMarker(event.latLng, true)});
  //directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  map.setOptions({draggableCursor:'crosshair'});
  setRM = 1;
 } else {
  map.setOptions({draggableCursor: null});
  g.event.removeListener(temp);
  setRM = 0;
 }
}

var image = {
    url: 'http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/ridefinder-images/mm_20_red.png',
  };

var mIndex = 0;
// OSM YOURS DIRECTION Service//
function addMarker(latlng) {

 marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: latlng,
  icon:  image,
  map: map,
  title: latlng.toUrlValue(6),
  draggable: true
 })
 marker.name = mIndex;
 mIndex++;

 routeMarkers.push(marker);
 //info.innerHTML = 'Test:' +mIndex +" / " + routeMarkers.length
 testUrl = 'http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=kml&flat=52.215676&flon=5.963946&tlat=52.2573&tlon=6.1799&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik'
 if (routeMarkers.length == 1) {httpGet(testUrl)}; //for testing
 if (routeMarkers.length > 1) {
  getRequest();
 }
}

function getRequest() {
 str = 'http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=kml&'
  + 'flat={startLat}&flon={startLon}&tlat={endLat}&tlon={endLon}&v=bicycle&fast=1&layer=mapnik'
 start = routeMarkers[routeMarkers.length - 2].getPosition().toUrlValue(6);;
 end =   routeMarkers[routeMarkers.length - 1].getPosition().toUrlValue(6);
 s = start.split(",");
 e = end.split(",");
 startLat = s[0]; startLon = s[1];
 endLat = e[0]; endLon = e[1];
 //alert(endLon);
 str = str.replace("{startLat}", startLat);
 str = str.replace("{startLon}", startLon);
 str = str.replace("{endLat}", endLat);
 str = str.replace("{endLon}", endLon);
 //alert(str);
 //window.clipboardData.setData("Text", str);
 data = httpGet(str);
 //alert(data.length);
 if (data == "x") getRequest();
 //alert(data);
 coord = data.split("<coordinates>")
 coord = coord[1].split("</coordinates>")
 coord = coord[0].trim();
 //alert(coord);
 //window.clipboardData.setData("Text", coord);
 var path = [];
 var clines = coord.split("\n");
 for (i=0; i<clines.length; i++) {
   iArray = clines[i].split(",");
  lng = iArray[0];
  lat = iArray[1];

  point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);
  path.push(point)
 }
 var polyOptions = {
   map: map,
   path: path,
   strokeOpacity: 1.0,
   strokeWeight: 3,
   editable: false
  };
 poly = new google.maps.Polyline(polyOptions);
}

function httpGet(theUrl)
{
 ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
 ajax.open("GET", theUrl, true);
 ajax.setRequestHeader("X-Test","test1");
 ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
  if(this.readyState == 4){
   if(this.status == 200){
    result = this.responseText;
   }else{
    alert(this.statusText);
    result = "x";
   }
  }
 }
 ajax.send(null);
 //info.innerHTML = result;
 //alert("OK?");  //!! this is needed for correct routing. Why??
 return result;
}

// Get the ball rolling and trigger our init() on 'load'
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', init);

</script>
 </head>
  <body>
<!-- Somewhere in the DOM for the map to be rendered -->
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<TABLE style="width: 512px;">
  <TBODY><TR><TD>
      <INPUT onclick="setRouteMarker()" type="button" value="Route">
 </TD></TR></TBODY></TABLE>
<div id="info" >0 / 0</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Were you able to hit OSM requests with negative latitude and longitude values? I am trying this API from "YOURS" where if the lat and lng are positive values, everything is working fine but if any of them is negative it is failing. Here is the request: http://www.yournavigation.org/api/1.0/gosmore.php?format=kml&flat=38.8999732&flon=-77.030323&tlat=38.8988335&tlon=-77.0349257&v=motorcar&fast=1&layer=mapnik

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. If I change the HTTP request fron asyncron to syncron then I can setup the route click by click correctly. If you are interested in the code (auto routing/direction with multiple, multiple, .. Waypoints) replace the http function from above with the attached http function.

If someone can improve the Http function with some error checking(regarding the comments from W3school), it would be fine.

best regards, Reinhard

```js
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
 var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
 xhttp.open("GET", theUrl, false); //asyncron = true doesn't work correct.
 xhttp.send();
 result = xhttp.responseText;
 info.innerHTML = result;
 return result;
 //Notes from:http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp
 //Using async=false is not recommended, but for a few small requests this can be ok.
 //Remember that the JavaScript will NOT continue to execute, until the server response is ready.
 //If the server is busy or slow, the application will hang or stop.
 //Note: When you use async=false, do NOT write an onreadystatechange function -
 // just put the code after the send() statement:
}
```