# ajax onclick event fetches wrong result first time but correct on second time

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

The problem is that first question loads with `onload` function now when I click a button to fetch the next question i.e. the 2nd question, but it fetches the first question again, after that, when I click next it fetches the 2nd question.
Now if I want to fetch the question from another subject, suppose maths section, where I have set the value of variable to 15, when I click maths it first increments the question and after that whatever button I click it still jumps to question 15.

```
var question = 1;
function ajaxFunction (_direction) {
    var ajaxRequest; 
    try {
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e) {      
        try {
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try {
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e) {
                alert("Your browser broke!");
                return false;
            }
        }
   }

   ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (ajaxRequest.readyState == 4 && ajaxRequest.status== 200) {
           var ajaxDisplay = document.getElementById('ajaxDiv');
           if (_direction=='') {
              question=1;
           } else if (_direction=='next') {
              question++;
           } else if (_direction>=1 && _direction <=90) {
              question = _direction;
           }
       }
       ajaxDisplay.innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;
   }
   ajaxRequest.open("GET", "ajax-example.php?q="+question, true);
   ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well, I haven't gave up and got the solution by myself and I'm posting this in answer so that if anyone else have the same issue.
I just removed the if else condition from the onreadystatechange and placed it above the function and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem and solved it by setting the HTTP request from asyncron to syncron (see [Autoroute step by step using Yours http request has a time lag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35816290/autoroute-step-by-step-using-yours-http-request-has-a-time-lag/35845511#35845511)).

Did you solve your problem on the same way or did you found a better one?

best regards, Reinhard